# Solution of a Laplace equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Laplace equation:

$\frac{\partial^{2}H}{\partial\,x^2} + \frac{\partial^{2}H}{\partial\,y^2} + \frac{\partial^{2}H}{\partial\,z^2}=0$

Head $H$ doesn’t vary in $y$ and $z$ directions. Boundary conditions are : at $x=0$, $H=5$; and 
$\frac{dH}{dx}=−1$. What is the value of $H$ at $x=1.2$ .
I have got the answer but cannot solve it. Please help me to solve this equation.

Comment: So...the problem really only involves $x$? So you are left to solve $H''=0,H(0)=5,H'(0)=-1$? That should be a very easy problem, just integrate twice and solve for the integration constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean by "$H$ doesn't vary in $y$ and $z$ directions" that $H$ is constant in $y$ and $z$ direction, the whole problem simplifies to an ODE:
$$
\frac{\partial ^2 H}{\partial x^2} =0
$$
Since 
$$
\frac{\partial  H}{\partial x}=-1
$$
we get that
$$
H(x,y,z)=-x+C
$$
Plugging in the inital conditions, gives us:
$$
H(x,y,z)=-x+5
$$

Comment: You are welcome!